# How do I return only type of resolve in a Promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, async-await, es6-promise

```
let companyInfo: PublicCompanyAPIResponseType;
companyInfo = await get<PublicCompanyAPIResponseType>({
    url: getCompanyDataURL,
}).catch(res => {
    responseStatus = res.status;
});
```

When i assign companyInfo variable to that get func

```
export async function get<T>({ url, headers }: ApiConnectSet): Promise<T> {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: headers,
    })
        .then(async res => {
            if (res.ok) {
                return resolve((await res.json()) as Promise<T>);
            } else if (res.status === 401) {
                const redirectPath = window.location.pathname;
                window.location.href =
                    '/login?redirectPath=' + redirectPath;
            } else {
                reject(res);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            reject(error);
        });
});
```

}

Visual studio code shows this error
[image]

How can my get function only return `PublicCompanyAPIResponseType`?

Comment: First you don't need `new Promise` because `fetch` returns one. Then your function is fine, but when you do `catch` you basically create a new Promise that is NOT `Promise<PublicCompanyAPIResponseType>` but `Promise<PublicCompanyAPIResponseType|void>` because your catch block returns undefined.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it), and don't pass `async` functions as callbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, if it works

```
let companyInfo: PublicCompanyAPIResponseType;
try {
  companyInfo = await get<PublicCompanyAPIResponseType>({
    url: getCompanyDataURL,
  })
} catch(err => {
    // get the status from error object and assign it to response status
    responseStatus = // your status code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just adding the `Promise<T>` in the return statement?

```
export async function get<T>({ url, headers }: ApiConnectSet): Promise<T> {
    return new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {
        //your code
    }
);
```